# Count number of Gmail emails per sender

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to do a mass cleanout of my Gmail because search has gotten so slow.  I would like to tally how many emails i've received from each sender.  The closest solution I've found is this: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102162/can-i-get-a-list-of-the-senders-of-all-of-the-messages-in-my-inbox however that only tallies emails in Inbox, not in All Mail.  I even tried moving all my 100k emails from All Mail to Inbox so that I could use it, but Gmail doesn't appear to let you move more than 3,500 messages in.

How do I adjust the Google Apps script to analyze All Mail instead of just Inbox? Or any other way of doing this welcomed too

```
function sender_list() {
  var inbox_threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();

  var sender_array = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < inbox_threads.length; i++) {
    var message = inbox_threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var x = 0; x < message.length; x++) {
      var sender = message[x].getFrom();
      sender_array.push([sender]);      
    }
  }
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(['Email Address']);
  sender_array.sort();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, sender_array.length,1).setValues(sender_array);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

This will get you a unique sender list

```
function sender_list() {
  var inbox_threads=GmailApp.search('in:anywhere');
  var sender_array=[];
  var uA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<inbox_threads.length;i++) {
    var message=inbox_threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var x=0;x<message.length; x++) {
      var sender=message[x].getFrom();  
      //prevent duplicates
      if(uA.indexOf(sender)==-1) {
        uA.push(sender);
        sender_array.push([sender]);      
      }
    }
  }
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet()
  sh.clear();
  sh.appendRow(['Email Address']);
  sh.getRange(2, 1,sender_array.length,1).setValues(sender_array).sort({column:1,ascending:true});

}
```

and this version adds the number of emails per sender:

```
function sender_list() {
  var inbox_threads=GmailApp.search('in:anywhere');
  var sender_array=[];
  var uA=[];
  var cObj={};
  for(var i=0;i<inbox_threads.length;i++) {
    var message=inbox_threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var x=0;x<message.length; x++) {
      var sender=message[x].getFrom();  
      if(uA.indexOf(sender)==-1) {
        uA.push(sender);
        sender_array.push([sender]);
        cObj[sender]=1;
      }else{
        cObj[sender]+=1;
      }
    }
  }
  sender_array.forEach(function(r){
    r.splice(1,0,cObj[r[0]]);
  });
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet()
  sh.clear();
  sh.appendRow(['Email Address','Count']);
  sh.getRange(2, 1,sender_array.length,2).setValues(sender_array).sort({column:1,ascending:true});

}
```

I have about 500 emails total.  I don't store a lot of emails and I discard a lot of unwanted emails when they arrive.  It took about 20 seconds to run.  So I would imagine 100K emails will require you to run this in batches.

[Batch Operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

The following code requires that that Gmail API be enabled.

To do a batch you could run this function to start with:

```
function sender_list_paged(token) {
  var token=token||null;
  var query="in:anywhere"; 
  var sender_array=[];
  var uA=[]
  var cObj={};
  do{
    var result=Gmail.Users.Messages.list("your gmail address", {maxResults:100,pageToken:token,q:query});
    var list=result;
    Logger.log(list);
    for(var i=0;i<list.messages.length;i++) {
      var sender=GmailApp.getMessageById(list.messages[i].id).getFrom();
      if(uA.indexOf(sender)==-1) {
        uA.push(sender);
        sender_array.push([sender]);
        cObj[sender]=1;
      }else{
        cObj[sender]+=1;
      }
    }
    token=list.nextPageToken
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("lastpagetoken", token);
  }while(token);
  sender_array.forEach(function(r){
    r.splice(1,0,cObj[r[0]]);
  });
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet()
  sh.clear();
  sh.appendRow(['Email Address','Count']);
  sh.getRange(2, 1,sender_array.length,2).setValues(sender_array).sort({column:1,ascending:true});
}
```

And then run the function again like this:

sender_list_paged(getLastPageToken());

```
function getLastPageToken() {
  return PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("lastpagetoken")
}
```

And I think that will work. But you may have to play with it as I haven't ever had to do that.

Comment: Thanks I was going for what the second script does, however it only processed the first 1123 emails in my inbox.  I looked at Batch Operations but not being a programmer myself, I wasn't sure how to edit the code.  Could you please expand the above code to handle a large amount of emails?  We all aspire to get down to 500 like you :)

Comment: I tried the batch process but it returned ```ReferenceError: "Gmail" is not defined```.  What I did to get there was copy and past both sender_list_paged and getLastPageToken.  Then I pressed the play button. I tried a few other variations of things but nothing worked for me

Comment: Enable the Gmail API:
  Enable Gmail API here: https://console.developers.google.com/
  Then enable for this apps script project in Sheets / Tools / Script Editor, then Resources / Advanced Google Services / Gmail API: on.

Comment: Thank you for this, is there a way to also expand this and, not only show the number of emails, but also the SUM of the "Size" (in MBs) of these emails ?  I'm trying to clean-up my Gmail and I feel this will greatly help me identify the usual promotional emails that make it to my "Inbox".  Thx

Comment: This does not answer the question: how to get 'all mails' instead of just the inbox?

Comment: I am attempting to do the same as the OP. I have a working script. There are two issues though: 1) sheets only allows 6 minutes for a non-paid account to run a script which isn't enough for a big mailbox and 2) even after breaking it up I exceeded my daily use of the Google API.

Comment: @user1612851 these are user specific issues that I can't reproduce.  So I would just say that  you need to limit the scope of your query.  Good Luck.  I never have had issues like that because I delete all unwanted email via script and I protect my wanted email by maintaining both a black list and a white list.  And I allow the white listed email to bypass the filter process.  It's really a lot more complicated than I can address here. And probably most users would want to perform the daily process that I'm willing to do in order to avoid having a bunch of crap in my accountt.

Comment: Here's a complete version of the script with batch operations that looks for all unread emails in your inbox and runs the count function. Should work out of the box for you once your permissions are enabled!

https://gist.github.com/d-neri/65d6646504cb6cf49ea829b35b73dd11

Comment: What's the purpose of `var uA=[]`? I think it's unused.

Comment: Based on the provided answer by @Cooper I prepared a script which processes the emails in batches and takes runtime limit into consideration.

I leave it here if someone comes across this topic:
https://gist.github.com/fabianem/5012c0b9b44d0bd2c167ab7c81a82937