# Count Number of Emails in Inbox by Sender

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Referencing [another user's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216693/count-number-of-gmail-emails-per-sender), I've been attempting to obtain the number of emails for each email address, from within my Gmail Inbox. I was sure to enable to Gmail API in Google Developer Console, as well as in the Google Apps Script. However, upon running the script, I receive an error which states

> **"Exception: Invalid argument: value (line 22, file "Code")"**.

I've been searching Google for some answers, but my lack of understanding has hindered my progress.

Below is the full code, excluding my email address. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
function sender_list_paged(token) {
  var token=token||null;
  var query="in:inbox"; 
  var sender_array=[];
  var uA=[]
  var cObj={};
  do{
    var result=Gmail.Users.Messages.list("MY-EMAIL@gmail.com", {maxResults:10,pageToken:token,q:query});
    var list=result;
    Logger.log(list);
    for(var i=0;i<list.messages.length;i++) {
      var sender=GmailApp.getMessageById(list.messages[i].id).getFrom();
      if(uA.indexOf(sender)==-1) {
        uA.push(sender);
        sender_array.push([sender]);
        cObj[sender]=1;
      }else{
        cObj[sender]+=1;
      }
    }
    token=list.nextPageToken;
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("lastpagetoken", token);
  }
  while(token);
  sender_array.forEach(function(r){
    r.splice(1,0,cObj[r[0]]);
  });
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet()
  sh.clear();
  sh.appendRow(['Email Address','Count']);
  sh.getRange(2, 1,sender_array.length,2).setValues(sender_array).sort({column:1,ascending:true});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216693/count-number-of-gmail-emails-per-sender) you are referring to has a workable solution that runs:

```
function sender_list() {
  var inbox_threads=GmailApp.search('in:anywhere');
  var sender_array=[];
  var uA=[];
  var cObj={};
  for(var i=0;i<inbox_threads.length;i++) {
    var message=inbox_threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var x=0;x<message.length; x++) {
      var sender=message[x].getFrom();  
      if(uA.indexOf(sender)==-1) {
        uA.push(sender);
        sender_array.push([sender]);
        cObj[sender]=1;
      }else{
        cObj[sender]+=1;
      }
    }
  }
  sender_array.forEach(function(r){
    r.splice(1,0,cObj[r[0]]);
  });
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet()
  sh.clear();
  sh.appendRow(['Email Address','Count']);
  sh.getRange(2, 1,sender_array.length,2).setValues(sender_array).sort({column:1,ascending:true});

}
```

### Desclaimer:

The code used in this post comes from here:

> [Count number of Gmail emails per sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216693/count-number-of-gmail-emails-per-sender)

Comment: You're absolutely right, my bad. Script ran perfectly, and I was able to sort it from most to least emails in Google Sheets. Huge help cleaning the inbox.