# Extracting Emails from Gmail Label to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Im trying to extract emails from a specific Gmail Label to Google sheet, using Google App Script, the data in Google sheet to have timestamp, from email, to email, subject, and email body.

[image]

I have tried using this App Script from the link below but i am getting error message when i run it.

// Original: https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/gmail-to-google-sheets-script/

[image: Doc link]

Comment: Code should be in the question. See [mcve]

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: @theMaster im not able to add the complete code as its too long and im getting error message when i paste it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting Emails

```
function ExtractingEmails(query="Label:Test") {
  let o = [["TimeStamp", "From", "To", "Subject", "Body"]];
  const ts = GmailApp.search(query);
  ts.forEach(t => {
    let ms = t.getMessages();
    ms.forEach(m => {
      o.push([m.getDate(), m.getFrom(), m.getTo(), m.getSubject(), m.getPlainBody()])
    })
  })
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  if (o && o.length > 1) {
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
    ss.toast(`${o.length - 1} messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  } else {
    ss.toast(`No messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks you this works , I edited [SpreadsheetApp.openById] so it detects my sheet easily, but i am only able to get 527 emails, how do i get the complete email label, it has close to 5000 emails,

Comment: You will probably have to use nextPageToken and iterate through all of the collections.  I'll see if I can find an example for you.

Comment: [Here's an example using Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59222719/7215091)

Comment: This is great, thx. is there a way to download attachments in the email, creating one more field to the right that would contain that?