# Extract Email Threads from Gmail Labels to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

*as continued from my earlier post
[Extracting Emails from Gmail Label to Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74337062/16366541)*

Im trying to extract emails from a Single Gmail Label to Google sheet, using Google App Script, the data in Google sheet to have timestamp, from email, to email, subject, and email body, the script below credits @Cooper

The below script works and i could extract 527 emails from the Gmail label, but i am unable to to extract all emails from this label as i have approximately 5000+ emails in it, can Google Appscript do this in a single run?

```
function ExtractingEmails(query="Label:Test") {
  let o = [["TimeStamp", "From", "To", "Subject", "Body"]];
  const ts = GmailApp.search(query);
  ts.forEach(t => {
    let ms = t.getMessages();
    ms.forEach(m => {
      o.push([m.getDate(), m.getFrom(), m.getTo(), m.getSubject(), m.getPlainBody()])
    })
  })
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  if (o && o.length > 1) {
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
    ss.toast(`${o.length - 1} messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  } else {
    ss.toast(`No messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `extract all emails from the label approximately 5000 emails`. In your question, do you want to retrieve the emails from 5000 labels? Or, do you want to retrieve 5000 emails from one label? By the way, in your situation, can you provide the error message?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike I need to retrieve approximately 5000+ emails from a single label, Sorry for my bad english grammar, i have edited my post to correct this

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. If an error occurs in your script, can you provide the error message?

Comment: @Tanaike The script provided  works well to extract upto 527 emails to Google sheet, but i am unable to figure out how to get all 5000+ emails to Google sheet, the current script after extracting the 527 emails gives a error message [Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.showNotification() from this context]

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your error message of `[Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.showNotification() from this context]`, unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your error message and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike What details would you require?

Comment: If you call your function directly from the Apps Script editor, I suggest you replace `ss.toast` with `console.log` so you will see the logs in the place you are. Are you 100% sure that you have more than 500 emails in this label ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that the discussion has already been advanced. In this case, I would like to respect the existing discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery) for `GmailApp.search` it does not work well when there are lots of threads to retrieve.

So you need to iterate over them until there are no more with the variant of `search`.

Adapting your function, that would do

```
function ExtractingEmails(query="Label:Test") {
  let o = [["TimeStamp", "From", "To", "Subject", "Body"]];
  const PAGE_SIZE = 500;
  let index = 0;
  console.log(`Getting threads from ${index} to ${index + PAGE_SIZE}`)
  let ts = GmailApp.search(query, index, PAGE_SIZE);
  while(ts.length > 0) {
    console.log(`Retrieved ${ts.length} threads`)
    ts.forEach(t => {
      let ms = t.getMessages();
      ms.forEach(m => {
        o.push([m.getDate(), m.getFrom(), m.getTo(), m.getSubject(), m.getPlainBody()])
      })
    })
    index += PAGE_SIZE
    console.log(`Getting threads from ${index} to ${index + PAGE_SIZE}`)
    ts = GmailApp.search(query, index, PAGE_SIZE);
  }
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  if (o && o.length > 1) {
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
    console.log(`${o.length - 1} messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  } else {
    console.log(`No messages found for Query: ${query}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked!!!!  it extracted all 5000+ emails, thank you